# Garbage values in Matrix?

Tags: c

So I'm creating a Matrix structure however, when I try to populate the data, (see `populateArray` in MatrixTest.c) all of my values are junk with the exception of the last value. Is there something wrong with how I allocated my memory or is it because of the scope of my variable (`int data`) or is it something else?

Appreciate it!

MatrixImpl.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Matrix.h"

void* getter( Matrix* matrix, int x, int y )
{
  return getItem( matrix, x, y );
}

void setter( Matrix* matrix, int x, int y, void* const data, void (*userSetter)( Matrix*, int, int, void* const ) )
{
  if( checkBounds( matrix, x, y ) ) 
  {  
    userSetter( matrix, x, y, data );
  }
}

void dtor( Matrix* matrix )
{
  if( matrix->data )
  {
    free( matrix->data );
    matrix->data = NULL;
  }
}

void ctor( Matrix* matrix, void* const data )
{
  matrix->data = data;
}

//returns true if in boundary of array
bool checkBounds( Matrix* matrix, int x, int y )
{
  return ( matrix->stride.size2 > y &&  y >= 0 ) && ( matrix->stride.size1 > x && x >= 0 );    
}

void* getItem( Matrix* matrix, int x , int y )
{  
  if( checkBounds( matrix, x, y ) ) 
  { 
    return matrix->data +  matrix->stride.size1 * y + x;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Matrix.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdbool.h>

#define for_each( loopmaxX, loopmaxY, ... ) for( int y = 0; y < loopmaxY; y++ ){ for( int x = 0; x < loopmaxX; x++) { { __VA_ARGS__ } } } 

typedef struct
{
  void* data;  
  struct
  {
    int size1;
    int size2;
  } stride;
  
} Matrix;

void ctor( Matrix* , void* const );

void setter( Matrix*, int , int, void* const, void (*userSetter)(Matrix*, int, int, void* const));

void* getter( Matrix*, int, int );

void* getItem( Matrix*, int, int );

bool checkBounds( Matrix*, int, int );

void dtor( Matrix* );
```

MatrixTest.c

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "Matrix.h"

void userSet( Matrix*, int, int, int* const );
void testIntAt( Matrix*, int, int , int );
void checkForNullData( Matrix* );
void checkBoundsForLoop( Matrix* );
void populateArray( Matrix* );
void checkMatrix( Matrix* );

int main()
{
  Matrix matrix = { .data = NULL, .stride.size1 = 3, .stride.size2 = 3};
  checkForNullData( &matrix );
  int* chunck = (int*) malloc( sizeof( int ) * matrix.stride.size1 * matrix.stride.size2 );
  ctor( &matrix, chunck );
  populateArray( &matrix );
  checkMatrix( &matrix );
  dtor( &matrix );
}


void testIntAt( Matrix* matrix, int x, int y, int data )
{
  assert( *(int*)getter( matrix, x, y ) == data );
}

void checkForNullData( Matrix* matrix )
{
  assert( matrix->data == NULL );
}

void userSet( Matrix* matrix, int x, int y, int* const data ) 
{
  *(int*)getter( matrix, x, y ) = *data;
  printf( " %d\n", *(int*)getter( matrix, x, y ) ); 
}

void checkBoundsForLoop( Matrix* matrix )
{
  for_each( 
      matrix->stride.size1, matrix->stride.size2,
      assert( checkBounds( matrix, x, y ) );
  );
}

void populateArray( Matrix* matrix ) 
{
  for_each( 
      matrix->stride.size1, matrix->stride.size2,
      int data = x + matrix->stride.size1 * y;
      setter( matrix, x, y, &data, &userSet );
  );
  printf( "end populateArray\n" );
}

void checkMatrix( Matrix* matrix ) 
{
  for_each( 
      matrix->stride.size1, matrix->stride.size2, 
      printf( " %d\n", *(int*)getter( matrix, x, y ) );
  );
}
```

Example of output.
Whats desired:

```
 0
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
```

What I get:

```
 50462976
 67305985
 84148994
 100992003
 117835012
 134678021
 526086
 2055
 8
```

Comment: Why is `data` a void pointer? Didn't you get compiler warnings?

Comment: Trying to make a generic implementation so i can have this be a matrix if any data type.

Comment: Is there a reason I would get a warning for having a pointer to void in a struct Jabberwocky?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `getItem`, this isn't doing what you expect:

```
return matrix->data +  matrix->stride.size1 * y + x;
```

First pointer arithmetic on a `void *` is not defined by the C standard although some compilers allow it as an extension, treating it the same way as a `char *`.  Assuming that's the case, this is incrementing the pointer not by the number of *elements* but by the number of *bytes*.  You need to multiply that number by the element size.

So you need to add an extra field to `Matrix`:

```
typedef struct
{
  void* data;  
  struct
  {
    int size1;
    int size2;
    int esize;
  } stride;
  
} Matrix;
```

Change the getter to use it:

```
void* getItem( Matrix* matrix, int x , int y )
{  
  if( checkBounds( matrix, x, y ) ) 
  { 
    return (char *)matrix->data + (matrix->esize * (matrix->stride.size1 * y + x));
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Change `ctor` to set it:

```
void ctor( Matrix* matrix, void* const data, int esize )
{
  matrix->data = data;
  matrix->esize = esize;
}
```

And the call to `ctor`:

```
ctor( &matrix, chunck, sizeof(int) );
```

Also, `userSet` doesn't match the function pointer type `setter` expects.  Function pointers need to agree on the number and types of parameters and the return type.  In this case the last argument has type `int* const data` but the function pointer argument's last argument expects type `void* const data`.  So change the function last parameter type to match and change the body accordingly.

```
void userSet( Matrix* matrix, int x, int y, void* const data ) 
{
  void *element = getter( matrix, x, y );
  *(int*)element = *(int*)data;
  printf( " %d\n", *(int*)element ); 
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. I'd hug you if I could brother.